# How to add compound control to a layout at runtime?

Tags: android, runtime, custom-controls

I created a compound control using xml, and am able to re-use it by placing in other xml
layouts. But i want to add it at runtime using java code. I tried the following code but only the textview is visible and the compound-control is not shown...

I am quiet new to android so would appreciate any help or suggestions..

**COMPOUND - CONTROL LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_lines"

>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/msg_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAMPLE MESSAGE TITLE"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_shw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="SHOW MSG"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_dis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text=" DISABLE"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_del"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text=" DELETE "
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

**COMPOUND-CONTROL CODE**

```
public class RemainderControl extends LinearLayout
{
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
    TextView tv1;
    public RemainderControl(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.remainder_control,this);

        loadviews();
    }

    public RemainderControl(Context context,AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.remainder_control,this);

        loadviews();


    }

    private void loadviews()
    {
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_shw);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_dis);
        btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_del);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.msg_title);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                tv1.setText("SHOW BUTTON PRESSED");     
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                tv1.setText("DISABLE BUTTON PRESSED");      
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                tv1.setText("DELETE BUTTON PRESSED");
            }
        });
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                tv1.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CODE TO ADD CONTROL**

```
public class RemainderList extends Activity 
{
    ScrollView sv1;
    LinearLayout ll1;
    deepak.android.remainder.RemainderControl rc1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int ht=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int wt=LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

        sv1=new ScrollView(this);
        ll1=new LinearLayout(this);
        ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv1.addView(ll1);

        TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("THIS IS SAMPLE TEXT");
        ll1.addView(tv1,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wt,ht));

        rc1=new deepak.android.remainder.RemainderControl(this);
        ll1.addView(rc1,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wt,ht));

        setContentView(sv1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your control is included in xml, `public RemainderControl(Context context,AttributeSet attrs)` constructor is invoked. But in your code you directly invoke constructor `public RemainderControl(Context context)`. Move all your code that inflates the layout and sets the listeners into some method (for example `init()`) and call it in both constructors.

Comment: when i place the "LayoutInflater..."  code in a separate method i shows an error as 'context' is not visible inside the method. So i duplicated the code to both the constructors and it works fine now. But am i doing something wrong. Should i be able to make it work with out the duplication.i made changes to the code above as well which make it work now.

Comment: Sure you can do it w/o duplication. Just pass context as the parameter to the `init` method. Something like `private void init(Context context){//do the things}` and invoke it in constructors like `init(context);`